# Select a count of record sharing the same value than record X

Tags: postgresql

Figure a table with two columns: `id`, `catId`

How to select the records having the same `catId` than the record having `id` = 3?

Example:

```
id catId
1   3
2   4
3   4
4   4
5   3
```

1. Input: 3
2. Then catId of {id = 3} is 4
3. Then count of records having {catId = 4} is 3
4. Output: 3 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (catId)
WHERE t1.id = 3
```

If `id` column is not unique then

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (catId)
WHERE t1.id = 3
```